# $F:M\to N$ is surjective if $\int_M F^* \eta \ne 0$ for some $\eta \in \Omega^n(N)$

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, de-rham-cohomology

Let $M$ and $N$ be compact orientable and connected smooth $n$-manifolds and $F:M \to N$ a smooth map. Suppose $$\int_M F^* \eta \ne 0$$ for some $\eta \in \Omega^n(N)$. Then $F$ is surjective. Give an example that shows the converse is not true.

---

A non-surjective map has degree $0$ so the first part is clear. I could not think of an example for the converse, however. I want to find two compact oriented connected manifolds such that $F$ is surjective but $\int_M F^* \eta = 0$ for all $\eta \in \Omega^n(N)$.

Comment: @MoisheCohen Yes I'm looking for a counterexample

Comment: Choose $F$ surjective but null-homotopic.

Comment: I don't know if you read the deleted answer and all the comments therein before it was deleted. Are you still interested in an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a concrete realization of Mike Miller's comment. Think of $S^1$ as sitting in $\mathbb{C}$ and consider the map
\begin{align*}
\varphi: S^1 & \to S^1 \\
x+iy & \mapsto e^{2\pi i x}.
\end{align*}
Then $\varphi$ is both surjective and null-homotopic and thus serves as a counterexample.